# UIScrollView calls layoutSubviews() each time its scrolled

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiscrollview

I subclassed UIScrollView (IPhone SDK) and overrode the (void)layoutSubviews; method.
I noticed that each time the scrollView is scrolled, this method is called.

Is that the correct behaviour or do I have mistakes in my code? If it is the default behaviour, isn't this a performance killer?

Sincerely,
heinrich

Comment: Why are you subclassing UIScrollView? Why don't you just add subviews to it?

Comment: I could also add subviews, but thats not the point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is the correct behaviour and it should be used to get a custom layout of your subviews. I have used it several times and haven't had any performance issues eaven with hundreds of items added.

A cut-out from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) on that topic:

> Subclasses can also be containers for
>   other views. In this case, just
>   override the designated initializer,
>   initWithFrame:, to create a view
>   hierarchy. If you want to
>   programmatically force the layout of
>   subviews before drawing, send
>   setNeedsLayout  to the view. Then when
>   layoutIfNeeded  is invoked, the
>   layoutSubviews  method is invoked just
>   before displaying. Subclasses should
>   override layoutSubviews  to perform
>   any custom arrangement of subviews.

Comment: I see, thats the expected behaviour of a ScrollView. Thanks!

Comment: If this answer was helpful, maybe you could mark it as correct :P. Thanks!